# Does this basic Google Maps V3 location demo work for you?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation.html

I get a grey page with latest Google Chrome (access to location allowed for this website), but no error messages. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of glitchy in Firefox 3.5.9 too.  After authorizing them to see my location.  I had to drag the page up to see a map.  It's worked normally on subsequent attempts.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I accept that Google Chrome (I use 5.0.375.55) can submit my location, the demo works.

**EDIT**: I also checked it with Firefox 3.6.3 and it was the same: Accepting the locating and I got the map. No reload or scrolling required.